# How can I tell the contents of a mystery gift?

Tags: league-of-legends

League of Legends introduced Mystery Gifts this last patch. Where you receive a random skin for a champion you own.

[image: An image of the mystery gift option]

I've given/received a couple of the gifts, and I wanted to know who gave me which skin and what I gave to others. Is there anyway to tell which friend sent me what skin? And is there a way to tell what I sent them?

I checked my purchases but I only noticed my recent skin purchases there.

[image]

Comment: I feel like this is something silly I'm missing. I've seen people on reddit show it somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured out where to check. In the Purchases tab there is a Gifting History button.
[image: A picture of the gifting button]

For some reason it wasn't showing up earlier today, there were some store issues going on when I looked for it earlier:

[image: Store error message]

There still seems to be some issues with the button, because when I visited my purchases tab later it was missing:

[image: Missing gift history]

But once you click the button you get the following information:
[image: My gift history]

Comment: I knew it was something silly, but glad it was on Riot's end and not me derping.

Comment: Note: This has been (temporarily, I imagine) removed because senders could see what Mystery Gifts they sent before the recipients actually saw them.

Answer (score 2):

After they receive the gift. a prompt will pop up and say "Dude has received *champion* *skin*"

Answer (score 1):

From my experience when you send a gift you received  message saying "Friend has reacived there neon stike vi".

When you receive one, it says what you where given in small grey letter on the frist line. Hard to see but it is there.

Answer (score -3):

There is no way to tell what you are sending or what you will receive.

Unless you ask people what they get, or people ask you got:

- there is no way for the sender to know what the receiver got and
- there is no way for the receiver to know who the sender is

Comment: I don't think you are right, but I could be wrong. For example, http://i.imgur.com/0ES9Pzx.png shows this guy's gifting history I just don't know where that might be in the client. http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/1pj6n6/mistery_gift_can_be_under_520_rp/